# Microsoft Bot Framework - How to get data from Azure Database to my Bot project?

Tags: c#, azure, bots, botframework

I have been building an basic bot with Microsoft Bot Framework. But it seems to be very little/fuzzy good information(guides) out there how to get data from Azure Database into my Bot project with C#? I tried with Entity Framework but it seems not to work with Microsoft Bot Builder, so i guess thats not the way either. So whats the easiest way to go? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Here's an example of EF in a bot: https://github.com/JasonSowers/DatabaseBotExample

Answer (score 1):

You can always add the connection string provided by Azure in your project:

[image: ConnectionString]

Comment: I know you cannot comment yet, but try to keep questions in the comment section as soon as possible